# How to redirect https request to https::www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I purchased a Hosting Account on GoDaddy and named it as **dev.anotherwebsite.com** 
 
Then I brought a new domain called as **www.website.com** 
The directory structure on the hosting account is as follows.

public_html 
    --------**Websitefolder** 
    --------------      Application files/folder.
    --------------      ssl.key 
    ---------------     .htaccess

**Websitefolder**  contains all the files for www.website.com

I have forwarded my domain www.website.com to direct to Website folder in the file structure. So now the requests are coming from dev.anotherwebsite.com to website.com and therefore, when I type website.com, the browser is not able to validate that the request is actually going to www.website.com because it redirects request from dev.anotherwebsite.com to website.com

BTW, www.website.com is not a subdomain.

I installed ssl certicates on the **Websitefolder** and tried to browse my website.
https://website.com/ works fine!
but when I try to browse https://www.website.com/
it throws me an error

> This Connection is Untrusted
>
> You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.99anchors.com, but
>   we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
>
> Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted
>   identification to prove that you are going to the right place.
>   However, this site's identity can't be verified. What Should I Do?
>
> If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could
>   mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't
>   continue.

The .htaccess contents are as below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Question! 
I am not sure if this is to do with the .htaccess or placing the ssl key in the root folder? or generating a new key for **dev.anotherwebsite.com**

Answer (score 0):

What is your SSL certificate type? Is it a Wildcard SSL?

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's Server Class 1 Certificate from StartSSL. Basically, the requests are coming from dev.anotherwebsite.com to website.com and therefore, when I type https://www.website.com, the browser is not able to validate that the request is actually going to www.website.com because it redirects request from dev.anotherwebsite.com to website.com

Comment: I tried the rules in the .htaccess but they dont work on www.website.com